# Disallow Bootstrap 4 modal to disappear when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm using a Bootstrap 4 modal on my website. In that modal I have 2 buttons: calculate and send.

I don't want that the window disappears when I click to calculate. How can I do that?

I tried to change the property of the modal to `display:block;` when I click to calculate but it doesn't work.

Here is the code of the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">SEND AN ORDER</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" class="form-group">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Organisation(optional)" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="meat">
              <option value="" selected disabled>Please select a meat</option>
              <?php
              foreach ($res as $meat) {
              ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $meat->name.';'.$meat->price_per_kg;?>"><?=$meat->name;?></option>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity(in Kg)" min="5">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="ui labeled input">
              <div class="ui label">
                +250
              </div>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number" name="phone_n">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="add_info" name="add_info" cols="40" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Additional infos(place to deliver,...)"></textarea>
          </div>

          <button class="btn btn-zco btn-md"  id="calculate">Calculate</button>

          <button class="btn btn-zco btn-block">SEND</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: Remove the modal related `data` attributes from the calculate button, ie. `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#myModal"`

Comment: Kevin, you haven't voted up a single answer on any of the questions that you've asked. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote, and show your appreciation for StackOverflow and the folks that answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your [data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp), which instruct bootstrap's JS to close the modal.

```
<button class="btn btn-zco btn-md" 
    data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" - <---- Remove these two attributes
    data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: IEven if i removed it it doesn't work. I added it when i search for a solution. When i click to send the modal disappear too.

Comment: @KevinNyawakira, based on the code that you provided, what you're saying is not possible. The modal will only be dismissed when instructed. So, either you're instructing it to or you're not. Currently, all we can tell is that your calculate button is telling the modal to dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

make Calculate button like send button and remove `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#myModal"`
ex.

```
<button class="btn btn-zco btn-md" id="calculate" >Calculate</button>
```

Comment: IEven if i removed it it doesn't work. I added it when i search for a solution. When i click to send the modal disappear too.

Comment: i want the modal to stay when i click on calculate and dissapear when i click to send. I edited the code above. I forgot to remove those classes. But even if i remove or add it it continue to disappear

Comment: `$("#calculate").click(function(){
    var meat=$("#meat").val();
    var meat_split=meat.split(";");
    var meat_price=meat_split[1];
    meat_price=parseInt(meat_price);
    var qty=parseInt($("#qty").val());
    var total=meat_price*qty;
    console.log(total);
    
})`